# using timezones in event schedulers

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table containing a column called `effective_date`. An event scheduler is running everyday at 12:00 AM. Now, when it runs, the event checks if `effective_date` is equal to the current date and if so, runs an update statement.

I am using only one timezone for my application. It will not change. Now, this is all working fine: But my problem is what if the time has been changed for some reason? For example, someone changed the system date from january 5 back to january 2, now the row containing the `effective_date` january 6 can no longer execute an update statement in time. I tried changing the timezone if mysql (E.G. '+08:00'). But this seems to have no effects if I manual change the date on my machine.

What should I do? Is there a way for mysql to get the time from a specific timezone not in my machine?

Comment: _"What should I do?"_ - not let this happen in the first place. This meaning someone messing with the system's correct time zone settings. This is a matter of access control far beyond the scope of your script/application.

Comment: @CBroe is it possible that the timezone settings might be changed for some other reason? For example, computer resets?

Comment: Not in any _properly_ set up and monitored hosting environment.

Comment: In your scheduled task can you try and use ``DateTime`` and ``DateTimeZone `` in some combination to get desired logic.